# how to write delete statement with inner join and subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

whats wrong in below query, its throwing error SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended".
Want to delete all payment_ids from two tables which are matching with ERROR_LOG err_payment_id
Please help me in correcting query.

```
TBLPAYMENT(PAYMENT_ID, OTHER COLUMNS)
TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID (PAYMENT_ID, OTHER COLUMNS)
ERROR_LOG(ERR_PAYMENT_ID, OTHER COLUMNS)

    DELETE TBLPAYMENT, TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID FROM TBLPAYMENT PYMT INNER JOIN 
    TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID PAI ON PYMT.PAYMENT_ID = PAI.PAYMENT_ID 
    WHERE PYMT.PAYMENT_ID IN (SELECT ERR_PAYMENT_ID FROM ERROR_LOG);
```

Comment: do u want to delete only one column ?

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant RDBMS.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find the syntax that supports `INNER JOIN` in the `DELETE` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 `delete` statements in Oracle.

```
DELETE TBLPAYMENT PYMT WHERE PYMT.PAYMENT_ID IN (SELECT ERR_PAYMENT_ID FROM ERROR_LOG);

DELETE TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID PAI WHERE PAI.PAYMENT_ID IN (SELECT ERR_PAYMENT_ID FROM ERROR_LOG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can't delete using Join in SQL Server. Also, you can't delete from multiple tables at a time using the normal Delete. Instead, Make it 2 delete statements like this :

```
DELETE FROM TBLPAYMENT
       WHERE EXISTS
       (      
          SELECT 1 FROM ERROR_LOG WHERE ERR_PAYMENT_ID = TBLPAYMENT.PAYMENT_ID
       )
DELETE FROM TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID
       WHERE EXISTS
       (      
          SELECT 1 FROM ERROR_LOG WHERE ERR_PAYMENT_ID = TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID.PAYMENT_ID
       )
```

Comment: You can delete with a join in SQL Server, but not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DELETE from TBLPAYMENT where PAYMENT_ID in (select PYMT.PAYMENT_ID FROM TBLPAYMENT PYMT INNER JOIN 
TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID PAI ON PYMT.PAYMENT_ID = PAI.PAYMENT_ID 
WHERE PYMT.PAYMENT_ID IN (SELECT ERR_PAYMENT_ID FROM ERROR_LOG))

DELETE from TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID where PAYMENT_ID in (select PAI.PAYMENT_ID FROM TBLPAYMENT PYMT INNER JOIN 
TBLPAYMENT_ALT_ID PAI ON PYMT.PAYMENT_ID = PAI.PAYMENT_ID 
WHERE PYMT.PAYMENT_ID IN (SELECT ERR_PAYMENT_ID FROM ERROR_LOG))
```